# Selenium WebDriver Firefox Error: API Rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, webdrivermanager-python

Using the sample test code from [SeleniumHQ github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/python/tests/getting_started/test_install_drivers.py), I tried to run this code:

```
def test_firefox_session():
service = FirefoxService(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

driver.quit()
```

The test resulted as a failed test, with the error:

**ValueError: API Rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN!!!**

The test cases for Chrome and Edge browsers were successful.

Any help is much appreciated, preferably using webdriver-manager

Versions:
Selenium: 4.1.5
webdriver_manager: 3.7.0
python: 3.10
Firefox: 100.0

Comment: This is very annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox drivers are stored in Github. A GitHub has a rate limit for API calls, so to increase these limits you have to provide a Github token. See more info here https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#gh_token

Comment: Doesn't work in my environment see https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/433

Comment: That sound highly suspicious, like a fishing attempt. Why on earth would there be a rate limit on downloading https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a github token and then pass it to .env. More details are inside the webdriver_manager repository https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#gh_token